# Chatbase transcripts not visible

Tags: chatbase

I'm having troubles trying to look at transcripts in Chatbase UI. The messages arrive properly (I also get the 200 response) and I can see them in the dashboard. Also the session flow works fine. The problem is that whenever I try to click on "VIEW TRANSCRIPTS" I always get the "Unable to load the transcripts. Please try refreshing the page" message.
I started using chatbase yesterday and I was able to get a few transcriptions visible every now and then. But today I tried several times and I'm not being able to see a single "VIEW TRANSCRIPTS" interaction being successful (I also tried viewing yesterday transcriptions, but I always get the error message).

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you question regarding the Transcripts feature. We have heard reports of some users experiencing issues loading Transcripts during periods when we are receiving high volume of messages. Aside from checking back at a later time, a workaround that has been successful is changing the date selections on your custom date filter. Specifically ending the date range a day or two before the current date. Apologies for any inconvenience this is causing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, even reducing the range to 2-days old messages seems not to work

Comment: @sean: I'm facing the same issue ("Unable to load the transcripts. Please try refreshing the page"), even for a single day. Can you advise with this, please?