# Chatbase bot: Unable to load the transcripts. Please try refreshing the page

Tags: chatbot, chatbase

I tried to apply the suggested method here:
[chatbase transcripts not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004424/chatbase-transcripts-not-visible)

So I filtered only this week  and the error is still shown. I'm also filtered past 7days and still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. It seems the problem has been appeared since the 30th of July when the Go 1.9 (GA) has been shutted down. Into the borwser console we see this call https://chatbase.com/transcripts/queue_transcript_fetch_job where the response is 503 "Go 1.9 is no longer available. Please refer to ... for more information."

Answer (score 0):

The Chatbase issue seems to have been resolved at this time.